# Hermite algorithm, inverse matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to do this exersise, but even though I know how to reach the canonical matrix ($B$) I don't understand the second part of the problem. Any help?
Here are the details:

The matrices
$A = \left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 0 & -2 \\
0 & -2  & -2  & -2  \\ 
\end{array} \right]$

and $B = \left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0  & 1 & 0  \\ 
\end{array} \right]$

are such that $B$ is obtained from $A$ by successive elementary changes in the rows and columns Find inverse Matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that.

$B=PAQ$, $(K={Q})$

Comment: Have you learnt the **elementary matrices**?

Comment: Yes I have. But how do I apply it.

Comment: You probably learned that to apply one elementary row/column operation is equivalent to do a left/right-multiplication by one elementary matrix. So if you know how to do row/column operations to transform $A$ to  $B$, what could you know about $P, Q$ then [Caution: such pair of $P, Q$ is no way unique] ?